# Pygsheets.authorize generating tmp files every time it runs

Tags: python, pygsheets

I am trying to run a simple code using pygsheets. This code has already been tested in other computers, so it is probably some configuration in my machine or OS. In the two lines:

```
creds_file = _google_creds_as_file()
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=creds_file.name)
```

The function `_google_creds_as_file()` returns a temporary file with certain name, and when I call `gc`, it always returns the same error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpwjie6exl'
```

This happens even when I run the Python script as an administrator. If I delete this file, another one, with a different name is generated, and the problem persists.

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: A file exists in that path?

Comment: Yes, the file ```tmpwjie6exl``` exists in the path. Every time I run it, it generated a different file.

Comment: And it’s actually a file not a folder, permission denied error does seem to point to something other than file not found error? Sometimes that means the file is opened by another process.